# Notate the probability that $70\%$ of Facebook users have Twitter accounts.

Tags: probability, notation

> Suppose $70\%$ of Facebook users have Twitter accounts. Write this as a probability. $$P(\text{Twitter and Facebook}) = 0.70\tag{a}$$ $$P(\text{Facebook | Twitter}) = 0.70\tag{b}$$ $$P(\text{Twitter | Facebook}) = 0.70\tag{c}$$

Which one is correct option? I’m confused about the difference between $(\text{b})$ and $(\text{c})$.

Comment: Do you know Bayes theorem, and the definition of $P(A|B)$?

Comment: @Jam, yes P(A|B) = P(A n B) / P(B) ... So. I think its P(Twitter | Facebook) = 0.70 , is it correct?

Comment: That's correct. It's the $B$ in $A|B$ that is what we're assuming. So, assuming `facebook`, the probability of `twitter` is etc.

Comment: @Jam, thank you so much.

Comment: it's c - read it as 'given that they have a facebook account, what proportion also have a twitter account'

Comment: b is 'given that they have a twitter account, what proportion also have a facebook account'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A|B)$ is defined as the probability of $A$ given that $B$ is true.  (b) would take all the people with Twitter accounts (B is true) and ask what percentage have Facebook accounts.  (c) would take all people with Facebook accounts and ask what percentage have Twitter accounts.  You just need to read the definition to answer the question.

The difference between b and c can be seen if you draw a Venn diagram.  Suppose a million people have only a Facebook account, a hundred thousand have both Facebook and Twitter, and ten thousand have only Twitter.  The chance of Twitter given Facebook is $\frac 1{11}$.  The chance of Facebook given Twitter is $\frac {10}{11}$

Comment: thanks for your explanations. It will helps me to difference of b and c...